# Create default related objects when instantiating model

Tags: python, django

Given two abstract models `A` and `B`:

```
class A(models.Model):
    some_field = models.Field(...)
    ...


class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, ...)
    some_integer = models.IntegerField(...)
    ...
```

How to create a set of related objects of model `B` every time new record of  model `A` is created?

So for example for every new `A` record by default there are 3 related `B` records with different values stored in `some_integer` field from `1` to `3`.

At the moment the most straight-forward approach seems to be using:

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=A)
def create_default_b_objects(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        #create related instances of model B
        ...
```

But maybe there's more elegant way by using [data migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) or [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/initial-data/#providing-data-with-fixtures) described in [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/initial-data/)?

Comment: Signals is the most elegant way to do it

Answer (score -1):

You can use `models.ForeignKey` field and give appropriate function to its `default` param.

Example:

```
def get_default_a_id():
    # you can place logic here which would create appropriate object
    # or return default shared object as it is in this example

    return A.objects.get(field="Field value which distinguishes default object").pk


class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, 
                          on_delete=models.deletion.PROTECT, 
                          default=get_default_a_id)
```